# How to get elements by a specific value of a custom attribute in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a custom attribute called **data-role** and I'd like to find all elements where **data-role="content"** in jQuery.

[image]

I'm currently doing this with some old JavaScript code:

```
var elements = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  if(elements[i].getAttribute("data-role") == "content") {
    // does something evil
  }
}
```

***Disclaimer:*** Code was not checked, just wrote it down quickly.

I've got a feeling that there's an elegant 1-line solution in jQuery, but I'm a novice. And I can't sleep before I know, so perhaps you stackoverflowers can help a bro out. ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys for the super quzick solutions, I used Abraham's selector. Need to wait approx. 15 minutes until I can mark as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("tagName[attribute='value']")
```

Or, in your case:

```
$("div[data-role='content']")
```

Will return the right elements.

From there, if you wanted to iterate over the set of elements that match this selector and `do something evil`, you could:

```
$("[data-role='content']").each(function(index){

     Do something evil
     $(this) is the current element in the iteration
});
```

Please note that the tagName is optional. JQuery selectors can be concatenated at will, so you can query simulataneously for tagname (simple string), id (prefaced by `#`), class (prefaced by `.`) or attribute (in square brackets as above), or for any limited combination of them eg:

```
 $("tagName#someId.someClass.someOtherClass[attribute='value']")
 $("[attribute='value']")
 $('tagName')
 $('#someId')
```

Are all valid queries, however keep in mind that jquery will only return elements that match ALL conditions in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Check out jQuery's list of [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).
You're looking for something like

```
$('div[data-role="content"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `attribute equals selector`

```
$("div[data-role='content']")
```

u can find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery select by attribute selector:

```
$('[data-role="content"]')
```

And for an array use `.each();` instead of `for`

```
$('[data-role="content"]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
});
```